# Is introduction of touch screen in DSLRs a boon?

Tags: camera-basics, body, rear-lcd

With Canon introduced EOS 650d with touch screen, does it have an useful effect on photographers?
Will this storm drive other manufacturers too or will it fade away just with this?
Also is there any **real benefit of touch screen in DSLR**?

Comment: Subjective, I'm afraid. VTC.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall not much I think. Just put your point of why or why not. thats it.

Comment: Right. And how are you going to accept an answer? There is no 'right answer' to this question. Some people might like touchscreens, some might not. This is a question more suited to a traditional forum, not SE.

Comment: Does this apply only to DSLR's, or to cameras in general?  The use of "a useful effect on photography" suggests the latter, which might influence answers considerably.

Comment: @D.Lambert to DSLR's.

Comment: Agree with @ElendilTheTall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Touch screens are "here to stay".

There are things that can be done better with a touch screen than with any human interface "I/O" method presently available on cameras. They add abilities at relatively low cost and are interactive and the interface is dynamically adaptive to meet situation and user needs.

Answer (score 2):

When shooting in the field, the touchscreen will be rarely used because it's slower to look at and then touch a screen rather than feeling a button and pressing it. Amateurs and casuals users are the target customer for touch screens in these devices. For previewing an image, many people will find it nice to swipe between photos and zoom in. But while-shooting, it's really all about the average joe - not so much the enthusiast/professional shooter.

Comment: Review this answer 2 years from now. I suspect that touch screens will be extensively used in professional systems.

Comment: They may exist, and in use during image review they will be great. However, in the field, when something is happening, it's ALWAYS faster to use muscle memory and flip dials and wheels without looking than it is to take your eye off the viewfinder and look at a screen, find what you want and then touch it.

Comment: @camflam - We will need to disagree. Discuss again in two years. I predict a major move in functionality based on touch screen or similar. Note that you do not HAVE to look at it to use it. To fully control a camera you need enough "bits" of control input to map your hand actions onto the total function address space. A button or roller tends to work at fewer bits per finger action than a keyboard. For total function access a keyboard should win .

Comment: I suppose; however, gloves, humidity, rain, dirty hands, etc will make the input less reliable than a dial and button system. Therefore, when speed and reliability is the issue, buttons and dials will dominate for a long time with pro shooters. Also, you can't rest your finger on a touch pad without input occurring accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

I found the touch screen to be a good addition to Canon 650D:

- iPhone-like pintch-to-zoom and image to image swiping with a finger.
- Compared to a 600D, I was able to navigate between different settings in Quick Control Display (when pressing the 'Q'  button) much quicker.

It is also possible to completely disable the touchscreen functionality should you so desire.